# Session management for big application (Java)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, servlets

My Question is a bit subjective and may be out of context,so please excuse me for that.

I am working on an application where we need to use Session in various places say

1. Store user preferences in Session.
2. Store some attributes in Session.
3. User profile.
4. Storing Cart in Session.

and many other things, more over we need to provide a clean way to let other use use the Session.
I know how to inject session or use it and how it works etc, so that is not an issue with me.

I am wondering about a way to create a Service say (SessionService) and let all API's use this to Work with HTTP Session.

Have any one worked/developed such Implementation, if Yes please share how best this can be done and any reference will really be helpful.

*Edit*

We are using Spring Security for Authentication and Authorization

Answer (score 0):

I firmly believe that the session should, wherever possible, remain as decoupled from the business logic of your system as is humanly possible.

By all means, when operating at a view layer, provide utilities to access the session but remember the following;

- The session object itself is not thread safe;
- Any attribute can be changed at any time
- Any attribute can be modified by any piece of code
- Testing anything involving the session is painful

If you are concerned with business logic then consider the following approaches;

- Implement a service tier

  - Handles business logic immutable objects
  - Transforms could be handled by custom adapters or [Spring convertors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html)
  - Gives separation of concern between view and business logic
  - Better testability (if that's a word)
- Manage temporary state in an in-memory object database rather than the session

  - Supports distributed replication so HA can be achieved
  - Supports transactional behaviour to allow consistency
  - Easily testable
  - <strike>Looks cool on your CV</strike>

I hope this helps. If not maybe a bit more information on your goals would help.